# No appenders could be found for the logger

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying some samples in spring mvc.I have three classes Student.java and StudentController.java as follows

Student.java

```
package mvc1;
public class Student {
   private Integer age;
   private String name;
   private Integer id;

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public Integer getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }
}
```

StudentController.java

```
package mvc1;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("login.do")
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

     return "result";
   }
}
```

I have a servlet xml file as HelloWeb-Servlet.xml which is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="Servee" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

and the web.xml file as follows...

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-  
       class>
    </listener>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the student.jsp and result.jsp files are stored in mvc11 package

student.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/Spring/mvc1/addStudent">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>${name}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>${age}</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>${id}</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

When running the spring program i am getting the warning message as follows

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

and the error message as

```
The requested resource (/Spring/mvc11/student.jsp) is not available.
```

the HelloWeb-Servlet.xml is stored under WEB-INF.I have referred a lot of source but couldnt fix it.Can someone help me with it...

Comment: The warnings concern log4j property file that is not found but the error you are mentioning as nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are multiple problems

1. The package `mvc1` is not added to `component-scan`.
   solution: Add the following line to `HelloWeb-Servlet.xml`
2. `@RequestMapping("login.do")` annotation in `StudentController` does not make any sense, remove it
3. You have a mapping for the url `/student`, but is trying to access `/Spring/mvc11/student.jsp`, either change the RequestMapping or the requested url